# When I run a unit test visual studio crashed

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

When I am working with a VS 2008 Team System solution with a very large number of projects VS crashes on me all the time.

Strange thing is that the other developers don't have the same problem and it has only been a problem for me the last couple of days. Don't know suddelny why i'm having this problem.

When i run a unit test it crashes and when i get rid of a bunch of projest from the solution and run the same unit test it's doesn't crash.

It has nothing to do with add ins, VS settings, the machine spec and i already tried reinstalled VS. It has something to do with VS running out of memory or something

Here are the steps i took so fare:
Reinstalled VS then rebuilt the solution, deleted all VS files like the .user file and deleted all add ins.

I also increaed my virtual memory. My machine isn't running at 100% CPU or 100% RAM at the time and there is no usful messages in the event log.

It crashes when i do anything really except opening and closing files, like running a unit test or going into debug mode

any suggestions?

Comment: Might be better answered on www.superuser.com - but one thing you might check is if you have gotten any windows updates (SP/ KB etc)related to VS2008 or .NET installed in the last 1-2 days which maybe the rest of the team dont?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't have a lot of info - no error messages, no steps you take to get the crash, no steps you've taken to troubleshoot or what the outcome was, not even what you mean by "very large number of projects"...

So when you say "it has nothing to do with add ins, VS settings.." it's hard to accept that on faith, (or even help you at all honestly).

First thing I would do would be to reset all settings with Tools | Import and Export settings..., then "Reset all settings".  I would make sure all extensions are uninstalled (not just disabled.  And I would delete my `.suo` file (been burned by that before).

If none of that works, a repair install or uninstall/reinstall would be next.  I'd also look at any new applications or service packs I've installed over the last few days.

Answer (score 1):

When using VS 2008 with ReSharper (5.1, 6.0 or 6.1) I had the same problem. After uninstalling a seperate NUnit installation the crashes disappeared for me.